# Bit utilities don't seem to work

Tags: c, bit

I am trying to specify some defines to set and get bits in registers, but they do not seem to work. I think it has to do with the addition of base and offset. When I specify these in separate functions, they do work but I do not feel like performing a function call every time I am setting a register.

```
#ifndef COMMON_UTILS_H_
#define COMMON_UTILS_H_

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef volatile unsigned int * address;

/* Get the adresse of a register */
#define GET_REG(base, offset) ((address)(base+offset));

/* Get the value of a given register */
#define GET_REG_BIT(base, offset, pos) *((address)base+offset) & (1 << pos);

/* Set bit of given register */
#define SET_REG_BIT(base, offset, pos) *((address)(base+offset)) |= (1 << pos);

/* Clear bit of given register */
#define CLEAR_REG_BIT(base, offset, pos) *((address)(base+offset)) &= ~(1 << pos);

/* Poll register until bit is set */
#define POLL_REG_SET(base, offset, pos) while(*((address)base+offset) & (1 << pos) != 1){};

/* Clear register */
#define CLEAR_REG(base, offset) *((address)base+offset) = 0x0;

/* Get int-value of a specivied range of bits - lsb starting at 0 */
#define GET_BIT_RANGE(x,msb,lsb) (x >> lsb) & ~(~0 << (msb-lsb+1))
```

Comment: Show us what works and what does not work and define "does not work".

Comment: You should put parens around each of your macro argument names in the macro definition.  Also, the macro definitions should be completely enclosed in parens. Finally, semi-colons are usually a bad idea at the end of the macro definition.I have no idea if this is contributing to your problem - it's just a general practice that should be followed to avoid problems when passing expressions as macro arguments.

Comment: Yea, sorry, all the values inside the defines are correctly set at runtime but when actually performing the operations, none of the values are set. Getters do return a value, so I think its probably only the SET_REG_BIT define that doesn't do what its supposed to.

Comment: You should know that `(address)base + offset` and `(address)(base + offset)` are not the same thing.  I'm not sure which you actually wanted but you are using both so that's wrong.  The first one will multiply `offset` by the size of an int, and the second one won't.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the issue is resolved. I changed these () so much, I kind of lost the overview in the end :)